# Database connectivity issue with Docker Linux Container

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, swagger

I am running .netCore 3.1 micro service API with swagger into Linux container, attached is my Linux base file [image].....
my API is running perfectly with docker file based on Windows image.
but when I run my API with Linux base docker file and click on any method its stuck in ages.

I am using SQL server 2016 installed on Windows server.
and here is my connectionString

```
   "TeamDBConnectionString": "Server=tcp:ip_of_database,port_no;Database=DB;User ID=username;pwd =*********;"
```

**is this because of platform conflict, my api is running under Linux
 and my configured database is under windows OS ?**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using the wrong Linux image try this in to your docker file

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0-bionic AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0-bionic AS build
```

also try this link, similar problem explained here [NET Core 3.0 Docker Container Won't Connect to SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58116807/net-core-3-0-docker-container-wont-connect-to-sql-server?rq=1)